# Dropdown is not visible unless the page is scrolled down. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

http://www.levybusinesslaw.com/index.php

The nav dropdown only works when the page is scrolled down. I've tried everything to make it visible, but nothing seems to work. Any advice on how to fix this issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Title -->

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700%7COpen+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js">
</script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<![endif]-->
</head >

    <!-- ==================================================================================================================================
HEADER
======================================================================================================================================= -->

    <section class="home-header">

        <!-- header -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="header-top">
                        <!-- logo -->
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-5">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" title="" alt="" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- .logo -->

                        <!-- quick contact -->
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
                            <div class="quick-contact text-right">
                                <p class="phone">410.998.2001</p>
                                <p>Serving The State of Maryland</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- .quick contact -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .header -->

        <!-- intro content -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- content -->
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="intro-content text-center">
                        <h2 class="white-text">
                            <strong>
                                <span class="rotate">NEIL LEVY</span>
                                <br />BUSINESS LAWYER<br>IN BALTIMORE, MD</strong>
                        </h2>
                        <a href="mailto:nlevy@lmcplaw.com?Subject=Inquiry" class="btn btn-default button-white">Contact Me
                              </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- .content -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .intro content -->
            <!-- Popout Slider Menu -->
                <div class="container-popup">
                <div class="popup">
                    <div class="popup-overlay">
                        <a href="#" class="item-button play"><i class="play"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="item-button share share-btn"><i class="play"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup-content">
                        <div class="popup-top-content">
                            <div class="popup-top-content-inner">
                                <div class="popup-product">
                                    <div class="popup-top-title">
                                        <h6>How can I help you?</h6>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="popup-add-content">
                            <div class="popup-add-content-inner">
                                <div class="section">
                                    <h6>Services</h6>
                                                                        <ul>
                                    <li><a href="http://levybusinesslaw.com/#practice" >Business</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="http://levybusinesslaw.com/#practice" >Estate Planning</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="http://levybusinesslaw.com/#practice/" >Real Estate</a></li>
                                                                        </ul>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="section">
                                    <a href="mailto:nlevy@lmcplaw.com?Subject=Inquiry" class="btn buy expand">Contact Me</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-menu popout-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="popout-menu-item"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="font-size:3em"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="popout-menu-item"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:3em"></i></a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <script>
                        $("window").load(function() {
                  $("#body").removeClass("preload");
                });

        $(".share-btn").mouseenter(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(".item-menu").addClass("visible")
            }, 500);
        });
        $(".share-btn").mouseleave(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(".item-menu").removeClass("visible")
            }, 500);
        });
        $(".item-menu").hover(function() {
            $(".item-menu").addClass("visible")
        });
        $(".item-menu").mouseleave(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(".item-menu").removeClass("visible")
            }, 500);
        });
        $(".container-item").hover(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(".container-item").css("z-index","1000")
            }, 500);
        });
        </script>
         <!-- Popout Slider Menu -->

        <!-- navigation scrolled -->
        <div class="main-nav scrolled">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container_toggle container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle button-white menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>

                        <!-- smaller logo -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" title="" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <!-- .smaller logo -->

                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" > 

                        <!-- main nav -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                 <li><a href="/index.php">HOME</a></li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/index.php#about">ABOUT</a>

                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/index.php#community">COMMUNITY</a>
                            </li>                                   
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="http://levybusinesslaw.com/index.php#practice" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PRACTICE AREAS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Estate Planning</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="/index.php#contact"> CONTACT </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://www.levybusinesslaw.com/blog/"> BLOG </a>
                            </li>         
            </ul>

                        <!-- .main nav -->

                        <!-- quick contact -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                            <li>
                                <div class="quick-contact">
                                    <p class="phone">410.998.2001</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- quick contact -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- .navigation scrolled -->

    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take `overflow:hidden;` off of `.home-header`.

Because the `dropdown-menu` has `position:absolute;` it is not involved in sizing `.home-header` so is not displayed.